# compass:server not found when running `grunt server`

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, yeoman

#### The problem

`grunt server` outputs this:

```
Warning: Task "compass:server" not found.
```

I uploaded Gruntfile.js here: https://gist.github.com/ComFreek/7289648
That's the default file I got after creating a new Yeoman project.

---

#### Details

I am reading [Building Web Apps With Yeoman And Polymer](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/yeoman/) and following the described console commands to run.

My system:

- Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
- NodeJS 0.10.21
- NPM 1.3.11

I've already executed these commands:

```
npm install -g yo
npm install generator-polymer -g

yo polymer
```

`grunt server` told me that I had to install Ruby and [Compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass).

- I installed Ruby from here:
  http://rubyinstaller.org/
  After installing, I also successfully whether Ruby has really been registered in the PATH.
- I used NPM for installing Compass:

  ```
  npm install grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev -g
  ```

  (I tried a local and global install of Compass. Neither of them worked.)

This is the exact output of `grunt`:

```
D:\test>grunt server
Running "server" task
Warning: Task "compass:server" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Elapsed time
server  4ms
Total   4ms
```

---

#### It works now...

Unfortunately, I still don't know the exact cause. I went through all of my instructions above again, and it just worked out of the box.

In any case, I recommend updating all packages. My version numbers are (last edited: 02.02.14):

```
[NodeJS v.0.10.24]
[NPM 1.3.21]
[grunt-cli v0.1.11]
[grunt v0.4.2]
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem but it was fixed after I've installed Ruby's `compass`:

```
# gem install compass
```

**Hint**: `gem` is the package manager for Ruby, so Ruby should be existing  in the system.

For Redhat's based linux systems, you can use the following to install Ruby and gem:

```
# yum install gcc ruby-devel rubygems
# gem install compass
```

For Debian's based linux systems, you can check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ruby-full`   

`sudo gem install compass`

Answer (score 5):

Install compass with the following command:

```
npm install -g compass
```

If you've installed node as a sudo user (which is not recommendable), you should add sudo to the command (and next time use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm))

```
sudo npm install -g compass
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After going through all of my instructions above again, I do not receive the error anymore. It works fine. I'm sorry for your time (for writing the answer). If anyone is interested, here are all version numbers: `NodeJS, v.0.10.24`, `NPM 1.3.21`, `grunt-cli v0.1.11`, `grunt v0.4.2`.

Comment: After installing compass with -g i still have the issue.

node -v: 5.10.0
npm --v: 3.5.2
grunt --version: 0.4.5

Comment: This solution requires additional installation steps as it's simply a wrapper over the ruby `compass` gem as described in https://github.com/ngryman/compass. The gem must also be installed (`gem install compass`). See the other answers for `gem` instructions. **Update:** You may not even need the `compass` npm package after the gem is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Install Ruby, add to env -> path variable, add to pathtext as per link below

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_installation_windows.htm

Then install compass in ruby.

Only this solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that worked for me was:

```
npm install ruby-compass.
```

I had previously installed compass like Paul said but didn't work.